# D3 node position after transform

Tags: d3.js, transform, positioning

I am trying to get the new position of the node after it has been transformed. In this case I am moving a rectangle across the screen. I was hoping to be able to access the transform on the rectangle in another context but this only shows the starting position of the node. How do I get the node's final position?

The problem seems to be related to the use of transition() in combination with a transform function ("myTransform" in the example below). I just can't figure out what is going on.

```js
var moveButton = d3.selectAll("#move");
moveButton.on("click", moveBox);

var myTransform = function(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.a + "," + d.b + ")";
};

var data = [{
  "a": 40,
  "b": 40
}];

var box = d3.selectAll("svg")
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("id", "myBox")
  .attr("height", "50")
  .attr("width", "100")
  .attr("fill", "green")

function moveBox(d) {
  box = d3.select("#myBox")
    .transition()
    .attr("transform", myTransform);
    
    // How do I retrieve the transform?
    //console.log(box.attr("transform"));
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="move">
    <input id="move" name="move" type="button" value="Move" />
  </form>
  <svg>
</svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, so you're looking to access the transform after the transition has finished. You can do so by [using the transition's .on method](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_on), as documented in d3-transition and [the life of a transition](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#the-life-of-a-transition). In this case:

```
  box = d3.select("#myBox")
    .transition()
    .attr("transform", myTransform)
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log(box.attr("transform"));
    });
```

Should do it for you.

Comment: Two problems: OP is using D3 v3, so it is `.each("end", ...`, not `.on("end",...`. Besides that, `box` is a transition selection, and the console will not show the transform. It should be `console.log(d3.select("#myBox").attr("transform"));`.

Comment: Gerardo's suggestion is more in line with what I am looking for. But it doesn't work. Here is the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/c3bkvy8q/3/